# Emacs and python-mode automatic indentation

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

python-mode automatic indentation makes a lot of assumptions, it seems, based on style. How can I configure the way it indents in certain cases, or alternatively, make it indent like vim.

For example, if I have the following function:

```py
def some_function(
    arg1,
    arg2,
):
    pass
```

If I go to the end of `arg2` line, press enter, and type `arg3,`, this is what I will get:

```py
def some_function(
    arg1,
    arg2,
        arg3,
):
    pass
```

What I want is:

```py
def some_function(
    arg1,
    arg2,
    arg3,
):
    pass
```

How can I make it do what I want here?

I've tried `(setq indent-line-function 'indent-relative)`, which sort of does what I want, except if I hit enter twice, the cursor will be at the begging of the line (it seems like it only examines the last line to determine relativity).

In vim, I can type `def some_function(` and press enter, it will automatically indent 4 spaces. If I type enter twice, it will still be indented 4 spaces. This is what I'd like most.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like this solves the automatic indentation problem that I'm experiencing. This is NOT how to get emacs to use vim style indentation. If I figure that out, I'll add it to this answer.

```lisp
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (setq python-indent-def-block-scale 1)))
```

Comment: This also makes `python-mode` more compatible with `blacken-mode`.